# How to display none with WebStorage

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Hi I want to do if referrer is example.com then hide some data for all pages I am using web storage but not working

```
<script>


if (document.referrer !== 'example.com/') {
// Store
localStorage.setItem('displaynone', ' <style> 

.top-bar{display:none!important;}
.woocommerce-breadcrumb{display:none!important;}
.register-benefits{display:none!important;}
.before-login-text{display:none!important;}
#colophon{display:none!important;} </</style>');
}

localStorage.getItem('displaynone');




</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: First of all, multiline strings do not work on single or double quotes. You have to escape them or use backticks. Secondly. You're not doing anything to localStorage.displaynone, you're just retrieving them and have it thrown into the void.

Answer (score 0):

hello this code will help you playing with webstorage.js

```
    var cookieStoragePlan = {
        create: function(name, value, path, domain, expires){
    if(!name)
        return null;
    var cookie = (name) + '=';

    var time = new Date();
    time.setTime((new Date().getTime())+1000*60*60*24);

    if(typeof expires !== 'undefined'){
        time.setTime((new Date().getTime())+expires*1000);
    }

    cookie += typeof value === 'undefined' ? '' : encodeURIComponent(value);
    cookie += typeof path === 'undefined' ? '' : '; path=' + (path);
    //cookie += typeof domain === 'undefined' ? '; domain=' +       

    encodeURIComponent(document.domain)  : '; domain=' + encodeURIComponent(domain);
    cookie += '; expires=' + time.toUTCString();

    document.cookie = cookie;
    //console.log(document.cookie);
},

getValue: function(name){
    if(!name){
        return null;
    }
    var reg = new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    var cookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var result = cookie.match(reg);
    return (!result ? null : result[2]);
},

isPresent: function(name){
    if(!name){
        return false;
    }
    var reg = new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return reg.test(decodeURIComponent(document.cookie));
},

remove: function(name){
    if(!name || this.isPresent(name)===false){
        return null;    
    }
    var time = new Date();
    time.setTime(0);
    var cookie = name + '=; expires=' + time.toUTCString(); 
    document.cookie = cookie;
},

clear: function(){
    var allCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var row = allCookie.split('; ');
    for(var i = 0; i < row.length; ++i){
        var pos = row[i].indexOf('=');
        var key = row[i].substring(0, pos);
        this.remove(key);
    }
}
    };

    var userDataPlan = {
storage: null,

init: function(expires){
    if(this.storage !== null){
        if(expires!=='undefined'){
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var time = now + 1000*60*60*24*expires;
            this.storage.expires = new Date(time).toUTCString();
        }   
        return true;
    }
    try{        
        this.storage = document.createElement('div');
        //this.storage.id = 'userDataPlan';
        this.storage.style.display = 'none';
        this.storage.addBehavior('#default#userData');
        document.body.appendChild(this.storage);
        if(expires!=='undefined'){
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var time = now + 1000*60*60*24*expires;
            this.storage.expires = new Date(time).toUTCString();
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
        },

        create: function(name, value, expires){

    if(!this.init(expires) || !name)
        return false;
    try{    
        this.storage.load('myUserDataPlan');
        this.storage.setAttribute(name, value || null);

        this.storage.save('myUserDataPlan');
    }
    catch(e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},

getValue: function(name){
    if(!this.init() || !name){
        return null;
    }
    this.storage.load('myUserDataPlan');
    return this.storage.getAttribute(name) || null;
},

isPresent: function(name){

    if(!this.init() || !this.getValue(name))
        return false;
    return true;
},

remove: function(name){
    if(!this.isPresent(name))
        return true;
    this.storage.removeAttribute(name);
    try{
        storage.save('myUserDataPlan');
    }
    catch(e){
        return false;
    }
    return false;
},

clear: function(){
    if(!this.init(-1)){
        return false;
    }
    storage.parentNode.removeChild(storage);
    return true;
}
    };

    var localStoragePlan = {
create: function(name, value){
    localStorage.setItem(name, value);
},

getValue: function(name){
    return localStorage.getItem(name);
},

isPresent: function(name){
    if(this.getValue(name))
        return true;
    return false;
},

remove: function(name){
    localStorage.removeItem(name);
},

clear: function(){
    localStorage.clear();
}
    };

    var StoragePlan = function(){};

    StoragePlan.prototype = {
handler: function(){
    return cookieStoragePlan;
    if(typeof window.localStorage === 'object'){
        //alert("localStoragePlan");
        return localStoragePlan;
    }
    else if(document.body.addBehavior()){
        //alert("userDataPlan");
        return userDataPlan;
    }
    else {
        //alert("cookieStoragePlan");
        return cookieStoragePlan;
    }
  }
      };
```